# Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue with Koa Server

Tags: node.js, cors, cross-domain, koa

First, please keep in mind that I already checked other similar posts and didn't find right answer to my issue.

I developed a client / server application.

Client part is in React, and served by "serve" node web server. It has to call REST services stored on my server.

Server part is a koa server (so node) and serves several REST services.

Both are installed on the same Raspberry Pi. This Raspberry is connected to my local network. I configured the firewall of my network to open ports to reach my client and my REST services. I also declared my React web site within the network in order it to be reachable.

So I can well access my website. But when I try to call my REST services from there (by clicking on a button), I got the following error (under chrome) : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://X.X.X.X' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403."

I tried to install koa-cors on my REST services, but no luck. I tried to configure it by adding origin:true, then origin:X.X.X.X, then origin:true,credentials:true, but still no luck.

On the website, I tried to access to my REST services through X.X.X.X, through localhost, through 127.0.1.1, but nothing better.

Please help.

[EDIT] code of the definition of my server

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();
const cors = require('koa-cors');
const PORT = 8067;

const Router = require('koa-router');
const router = new Router();
const Logger = require('koa-logger');
const respond = require('koa-respond');
const BodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');
const log4jslogger = require('./libs/logger.js');

app.use(cors());    // << deprecated. Find better method ?
app.use(BodyParser({
  enableTypes: ['json'],
  jsonLimit: '5mb',
  strict: true,
  onerror: function (err, ctx) {
    ctx.throw('body parse error', 422)
  }
}))

app.use(respond());

// API routes
app.use(Logger());
router.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));
app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  log4jslogger.warn(`${new Date()} : User server listening on port: ${PORT}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [@koa/cors](https://github.com/koajs/cors), this one is recommended now.